# Keeping track of data in multipage form validation through PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, browser

I am working on a PHP project where the client wants multipage form data submitted. For instance, here is the process the form follows:

1. Create new entity.
2. Determine entity type.
3. Fill in entity-specific fields.

On each page, the form is POSTed to the current page. Validation is performed server-side, and if validation is successful the user is redirected to the next step.

I've determined that, in order to keep track of the user's progress, session data should be used. However, my concern is that, if the user opens two tabs and goes through the form in parallel, how can I keep track of what entity is being processed in each tab? Is this a scenario that can even be handled at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different 2 approaches.

1. If a user allowed to fill 2 forms at once, just add an unique identifier to each, and keep track them in the session.
2. If not - the things become simpler: just keep track of the steps passed and just show a warning in case of the previously passed step submitted.

Answer (score -1):

This is a page flow issue. Do NOT use session to deal with it. You are correct that tabs or new windows would cause you trouble.

I don't really understand the point of this bit:

> On each page, the form is POSTed to the current page. Validation is
>   performed server-side, and if validation is successful the user is
>   redirected to the next step.

Sounds like a "post-back", but why? POST the data from the page to a controller (or script) that does the necessary ss validation. After validation, deal with the data how you need and determine what the next step should contain. Then send the input form for that next step down in the response. Repeat until you are finished.

Comment: Maybe I can provide a more "accurate" answer with a bit more info about the problem...but I KNOW that using the session to manage page flow/form data is BADBADBAD.

Comment: The form is not a postback. The controller for the form just is on the same page as the view. This is so that errors can be shown to the user if there are form problems. OTOH, your answer really isn't that helpful. Send the input form after validation? What strategy do you mean? There's no way to send POST data through a redirect.

Comment: This downvote still irritates me. A page that POSTs to itself is the very definition of the "postback" This is M$ parlance, I believe. Sorry to offend delicate 133t sensibilities. It also indicates a poorly architected site where separation of concerns is not addressed (circa Y2K technique). See the MVC pattern. Also, by using the session, you are using server resources to manage a pageflow concern. It is the lazy way around a design challenge.